# How to update CocVim packages by bash and quit automatically?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When I want to update my all vim packages, I do this:

```
$ vim -c PluginUpdate -c :q -c :q
```

I do the same for `:CocUpdate` but it quits immediately:

```
$ vim -c :CocUpdate -c :q -c :q
```

Now, I do it by:

```
$ vim -c :CocUpdate
```

But the problem is it will stay in vim until I quit manually while I want to quit vim automatically when update process is completed like `PluginUpdate`.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the two commands, provided by two separate plugins, are implemented differently: one is specifically designed to be used that way and the other is not. 1. See if there is anything in CoC's documentation that helps. 2. If you can't find anything useful, use their issue tracker to ask for a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can chain like this

```
 vim -c PluginUpdate +quitall
```

for Coc, you can use sync version: `CocUpdateSync`